# facebook login sessions & permission

Tags: php, android, ios, facebook

I built an IOS app and using the facebook login, but if I were to use php to extract data like user photos, friends list, do I have to get the user to approve on my web again or one approval will allow the logins to be done cross platform for web, ios & android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the Facebook Apps API, it uses short-lived access tokens, the default lifespan is 2 hours. So regardless of the platform/OS/application you're going to need to renew those tokens anyway. You'll have to setup your app(s) to handle error messages returned by the Facebook API, and respond accordingly, so when an access token expires you can renew it in the background without further user input/management.

As for utilising the user data efficiently, when the app connects the first time you'll simply extract the data you need, in your case user photos, friends lists etc., and store it in your apps database for usage. Then when the access tokens expire you'll just need to renew them accordingly.

The 'Facebook login' specifically, they provide some more functionality for cross platform usage. Read up on this at the following link:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/overview/v2.0#cross-platform

That anchor link should give you the details/info you're after.

Comment: thanks for explaining. btw, i am trying to retrieve the user's photos in the albums but just get an empty array. used the sample code but still same. do i have to get approval from FB to view the photos even as a test user?